# Calling nested functions in Javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to become more familiar with Javascript OOP and so I wrote a little test script but I keep getting an exception when I test it:

**Exception:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'day' of undefined
```

**Code:**

```
(function () {
    function Time (date) {
        var self = this;
        var timeInWeek = 604800000;
        var timeInDay = 86400000;
        var dateInMilliSeconds = date.getTime();

        self.add = function (num) {
            self.day = function () {
                var newDate = new Date();
                newDate.setTime(dateInMilliSeconds + (timeInDay * num));
                return newDate;
            };
        };
    };
    var date = new Date();
    var time = new Time(date).add(1).day();
    console.log(time);
})();
```

And when I run the test script outside of the IIFE pattern I am getting the exception `Time is undefined`, I am new to Javascript OOP so when I tried reading other Javascript libraries a good chunk was over my head. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `add` method returns undefined as it has no `return` statement. The problem is unrelated to the use of the IIFE.

Instead, the `add` method simply added (possibly overwriting) the `day` method when it was executed so the following would have "worked":

```
var time = new Time(date)
t.add(1);    // returns undefined, but has a side-effect of adding "day" to t
t.day();
```

However, I suspect that the issue is two-fold:

1. `add` should `return` *an* object of a compatible type for [Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining); this can either be same object (for a mutable design) or it can be new object (for an immutable design).
2. `day` should be added directly to each Time object; this would make it so `new Time(date).day()` would work.

For instance:

```
function Time (date) {
    var self = this;
    var timeInWeek = 604800000;
    var timeInDay = 86400000;
    var dateInMilliSeconds = date.getTime();

    self.add = function (num) {
        // The idea here is to return an object of the same type for "chaining".
        // Here I returned a new Time object (you'll have to work out the details),
        // although for mutable objects, "return self" would be appropriate.
        return new Time(dateInMilliSeconds + (timeInDay * num));
    };
    self.day = function () {
        // actually return the "day", whatever that is.
        return ...;
    };
};
```

---

While this is can be a nice exercise, for production code I'd recommend [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) unless there is as compelling reason otherwise. The source code for moment.js (which might make a good reference) is on [github/moment](https://github.com/moment/moment). The "add" (with omissions and additional comments) looks like:

```
add : function (input, val) {
    // mutate this objects data (but not methods)
    addOrSubtractDurationFromMoment(this, dur, 1);
    // returns the same object for chaining
    return this;
},
```

Comment: This is good information, thank you. I am aware of moment.js, I just wanted some JS OOP practice, I will take a closer look at its source code. I played around with a couple different returns, I noticed that returning `day` and any other function inside the `add` function as an object works as well. Is this not recommended? i.e. `self.add = function () { return { day: function () {...} } };`

Comment: Sure, it'll "work" here (as there is a `day` method-property of the returned object), but it might not be appropriate for the given task. What happens if the user does `new Time(..).day()`? Or what if they do `new Time(..).add(..).add(..)`? The former won't work because there is no `day` method on Time (only on the result of `add`) and the latter won't work unless the object returned from `add` also has the `add` method. For chaining it is *usually* best that the type of the result is equivalent (but usually the same) to the original object - such that all the same methods are allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You've missed a `return this;` (which must be there to allow daisy chaining)

```
function Time (date) {
        var self = this;
        var timeInWeek = 604800000;
        var timeInDay = 86400000;
        var dateInMilliSeconds = date.getTime();

        self.add = function (num) {
            self.day = function () {
                var newDate = new Date();
                newDate.setTime(dateInMilliSeconds + (timeInDay * num));
                return newDate;
            };
            return this; //this
        };
    };
```

Without the `return` statement, in `new Time(date).add(1).day())` the `day()` is being treated as a method of the value returned by the `add` method of the `new Time()` instance. If the `add` method doesn't return an object that has a `day` method, you're sure to get an error.

The `return this` is necessary only for chaining.
Your code would work fine with

```
var time = new Time(date);
time.add(1);
time.day();
```

OR

```
var time = new Time(date).add(1);
time.day()
```